# FTP upload in passive mode not working, It opens data connection and times out with "Data channel timed out."

Tags: ftp

```
220 Microsoft FTP Service
user user
331 Password required for user.
pass pass
230-Directory has 543,777,456,128 bytes of disk space available.
230 User logged in.
pwd
257 "/" is current directory.
cwd aa6
250 cwd command successful.
pwd
257 "/aa6" is current directory.
pasv
227 Entering Passive Mode (*,*,*,*,201,182).
stor sampleprogram
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
425 Data channel timed out.
```

The above is the FTP done using command-line. When I check with FTP client there is a file with 0 size created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a firewall or NAT between the client and the server that prevents a connection to the port 51638 (= 201 * 2^8 + 182).

If you are not able to transfer files to/from the server from anywhere/any other FTP client, the server was most likely not set up correctly. Particularly the Windows server firewall was not configured with a rule for a data port range. Another option is that the server is not aware of its external IP address. That would be the case, if the part you obfuscated (`*,*,*,*`) is not the same IP address you connected to.

See *my* article on [FTP Connection Modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes) for explanation of the network issues with FTP data connection.

And particularly see *my* article on [configuring IIS FTP Server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server) for instructions on configuring the firewall and/or the external IP address.

Comment: Thanks Martin, It works . Its due to external IP address.

Answer (score 0):

````
PASS 3.65.0-rc1
Response: 230 logged on.
Checking for correct external IP address
IP 192.168.2.18 bjc-bgi-c-bi
Response: 510 Mismatch. Your IP is 142.114.72.8, bec-bbe-hc-i
Wrong external IP address
Connection closed```

I am trying to connect to an ESP32 the IP is 192.168.2.71 but I got the previous message
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34624370)